# Error in the code when i try to build the code in xcode7.2 which is develop in xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode7.3, xcode7.2

Please help me.
I have one project which get build successfully and working fine when i execute (run and build )that project in xcode 7.3

But when i try to execute the same project in xcode 7.2 it give me error :

```
 building for iOS simulator, but linking in object file built for OSX, for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please help me.
Can an one help me the exact solution for this error.
So that i can execute and build the code in xcode 7.2

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried a clean and build?

Comment: yes.but it is not working.

Comment: In Project settings, General, Deployment info it may be set to 7.3 instead of 7.2.

Comment: Deployment target in set to ios version 9.0. Deployment target is for the ios version and not for the xcode version

Comment: Yes, of course. My bad.